# Android Button setOnClickListener call function to change button image

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an app with multiple buttons and the image will change depending on different requirements and variables. But, I cannot get the image button change to work within the function. The setOnClickListner will setup the function call and within the function will change the image within the button.

How do I change the image in the button?

MainActivity.kt

```
package com.example.sandpit9

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    imageButton1.setOnClickListener() { changeimageelement1(R.drawable.button) }
    imageButton2.setOnClickListener() { changeimageelement2(R.drawable.button) }

}
}


private fun changeimageelement1(imageButtonX: Int) {

imageButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton)

}
```

MainActivity.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="154dp" app:srcCompat="@drawable/download"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp" android:layout_marginTop="8dp" app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/> . 
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is there an error?

Comment: You are always calling the `setImageResource` on `imageButton1`, even in the onClick listener of `imageButton2`. Is this intentional?

Comment: What is the purpose of the argument `imageButtonX: Int` since you don't use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should not use the () after setOnClickListener, just use

`button.setOnClickLisener{
  //your actions go here
}`

Answer (score 2):

ClickListener method should be`setOnClickListener` not  `setOnClickListener`

A sample code:

```
 button.setOnClickListener{
    counter++
    textView.text = "Click counter : $counter"
 }
```

Check [this](https://android--code.blogspot.com/2018/01/android-kotlin-button-on-click-listener.html) tutorial

Comment: Many thanks the tutorial is perfect, is there any way I can move the code image change into a function? As I will want to have a set of buttons, with the code separated (ideally into in separate .kt files) . i.e. private fun changeimageelement1(imageButtonX: Int) {

imageButton1.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenbutton)

}